# how to Elevating Privileges for Chkdsk in a mass batchfile/Powershell script in a GPO

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

our SCCM was broken by an update. so broke we made a new one. according to sysadmin we will have to run some windows commands to get it running.  two of the steps require running at elevated privilege.  Instead of having help desk go through each PC manually it would be super nice if I could build a batch file or powershell script to do all this under a GPO.

As far as i have been able to tell there is no easy way to automate the elevated privilege portion of the steps

some pseudocode

1. run sysadmins "fix sccm" powershell script
2. run at an elevated Prompt : CHKDSK /F
3. Reboot
4. Open an elevated CMD and run the following command:
      fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\
5. Reboot
6. Install the SCCM Agent

all the options i have run so far, powershell script, run from shortcut, run in plain cmd, etc is that all require a button push or yes clicked.

we need it to run and restart without any user interaction.  this will save us thousands of man hours.

thank you very much for your help

Comment: You should be asking this question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

write your batch file/script
create shortcut to it
right click properties on the shortcut
click advanced
run as administrator
ok and apply
run that from GPO and that will bypass administrator issues.

Comment: this doesn't work.  still requires a yes button to be clicked when run.